# html category how to make it work?

Tags: html, categories

i have my website www.erce16mb.com and i wanna know how exactly to make the category check to work: http://erce.16mb.com/products.html

i need to add an id or something? (i am new in html)
this is a part of categories:

```
<h4>Catogories</h4>

<div class="row1 scroll-pane">

<div class="col col-4">

<label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" checked=""><i></i>All Accessories</label>

</div>

<div class="col col-4"> 


<label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"><i></i>Women Watches</label>


</div>

</div>
```

Thank you

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? I dont really know what you mean by "Get it to work"

Comment: i want when i select woman watches for example to show me only the products with the categorry woman watches. If i can add a class or something to every product. And when i check woman watches to show me only the produs what have that class/id if you understand what i mean. i dont know how to explain very detailed, my english is not so good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually one thing I notice is that you have given all your checkboxes the name 'Checkbox'. You want each group of checkboxes to have a different name. All checkboxes sharing a name will be part of the same family. Look at this example:

```
 <form action="demo_form.asp">
   <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked> I have a car<br>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

As you can see, the type is checkbox but because you are selecting from a group of vehicles, the name is vehicle for both. In your case I would make the name of each input in the first group of checkboxes 'categories' and the name of each in the second 'brands', etc.

Edit:

After reading your comment it sounds like this is a little more in depth than just using HTML. It will require some Javascript to pull in the appropriate items when the right checkboxes are selected. You can also accomplish this with PHP.

Comment: I would look into ajax when someone changes your checkboxes.

Comment: thanks, i will try to change the names and i will take a loot at ajax.